# Duda con función callback en un array

Tags: javascript, array, callback

estoy empezando en el mundo de la programación con javascript y me quedé estancada con un ejercicio sobre `callbacks`:

La primera función llamada `agregarHttp` debe completar la `url` que recibe por parámetro. Si recibe `"www.google.com"` debe devolver `"http://www.google.com"`

Para la segunda función llamada `procesar` vamos a ejecutar una función que recibimos por parámetro a cada uno de los elementos de un `array`.

Para esto debemos completar la función `procesar.` Esta recibe dos parámetros:

1. El primer parámetro es un `array`.
2. El segundo parámetro que recibe es una función (al que solemos llamar `callback`).

La función deberá retornar un `array` donde cada elemento es el resultado de aplicar la función pasada a un elemento del `array` pasado.

Si recibe como parámetros `(["www.google.com","www.yahoo.com"])` debe retornar  `["http://www.google.com","http://www.yahoo.com"]`

Este fue el código que intenté:

```js
    function agregarHttp (url){
        return "http://" + url;
    };
 

    function procesar (unArray,callback){
        let sitiosWeb = [];
    for (let i = 0; i<unArray.length; i ++){
        sitiosWeb.push(callback,unArray)
    } return sitiosWeb;
    };

    let sitioWebCompleto = (unArray, callback) => [callback(unArray)];

   /* function sitioWebCompleto (unArray, callback){
        return callback + unArray
    } */


    console.log (sitioWebCompleto(["www.yahoo.com", "www.google.com", "www.git.com"],agregarHttp));
```

Sin embargo, no logro agregar a cada uno de los elementos del array el `http://` (sólo al primero de ellos), estoy usando un `callback` de la función que agregar los "https://" es decir, llamando a `agregarHttp` en la función `procesar` para que esta pueda agregárselos a cada elemento del `array` que le estoy dando como parámetro pero no estoy segura si eso es posible o si lo estoy haciendo mal ya que la primera se lo esta añadiendo a un `string` y la otra pretendo que se lo añada a cada elemento de un `array`, ¿es ese mi error?

Espero puedan aclararme un poco el panorama. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Cambia esta llamada: `sitiosWeb.push(callback,unArray)` por esta otra: `sitiosWeb.push(callback(unArray[i]))`. Comenta el resultado. Recuerda usarlo así: `let sitioWebCompleto = procesar(["www.yahoo.com", "www.google.com", "www.git.com"],agregarHttp)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que nunca ejecutas la función `procesar()` que es la que debería recorrer cada elemento para agregar `http://` y solo lo agregas al arreglo, resultando en una sola cadena en lugar de elementos separados.

```js
function agregarHttp(url) {
    return "http://" + url;
}

function procesar(unArray,callback) {
    let sitiosWeb = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < unArray.length; i++){
        // Se ejecuta la función callback enviando el elemento actual como parámetro
        sitiosWeb.push(callback(unArray[i]));
    }
    return sitiosWeb;
}

let sitioWebCompleto = (unArray, callback) => procesar(unArray, callback);

console.log(sitioWebCompleto(["www.yahoo.com", "www.google.com", "www.git.com"], agregarHttp));
```

Aunque podrías simplificar si dentro de la función `sitioWebCompleto()` se recorren todos los elementos y, por cada uno, se ejecuta el `callback`. El ciclo se remplaza por el método [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
function agregarHttp(url) {
    return "http://" + url;
}

let sitioWebCompleto = (unArray, callback) => {
    return unArray.map(item => callback(item));
};

console.log(sitioWebCompleto(["www.yahoo.com", "www.google.com", "www.git.com"], agregarHttp));
```

Comment: POR SEGUNDOS!!!

Comment: @Benito-B, suele pasar. ;-)

Comment: @Triby ¡Gracias! Ya veo donde me equivoqué, pensé si estaba haciendo un uso correcto del callback al llamarlo como parámetro del .push()... estaba tan cerca .
La simplificación con .map() se ve mucho mejor, sin duda sería una mejor solución al problema

Comment: @AbrilFernández Recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada si te ha ayudado! (En este caso te recomiendo marcar esta respuesta de Triby, puesto que además de responder antes, si tiene un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo con el método `procesar()` implementado! )

Answer (score 3):

La función `procesar()` no la estabas usando, así que la he eliminado por claridad.

Por lo demás, te dejo en los comentarios los cambios que he realizado.
En verdad te faltaba poquito para tenerlo funcionando bien!

Cualquier duda que tengas, pregunta que para eso estamos.

```js
function agregarHttp (url){
  /*
    Tal como lo hiciste, esta callback no se ejecuta para cada miembro del array,
    si no que RECIBE un array así que mapeo ese array para añadirle el https a cada elemento.
    Es lo mismo que hacer un bucle for editándolos.
  */
  return url.map((u) => "https://" + u );
};

//También he eliminado el array que creabas aquí, para que se imprima más "limpio"
let sitioWebCompleto = (unArray, callback) => callback(unArray);

/*
 El problema es que aquí en ningún momento estabas llamando a la función procesar.
 Estás llamando directamente a sitioWebCompleto y pasándole el callback que será "agregarHttp"
 pero con un único valor!
*/
console.log(sitioWebCompleto(["www.yahoo.com", "www.google.com", "www.git.com"],agregarHttp));
```

Comment: ¡Gracias! Usando .map() quedaría mucho mejor.  Ya vi que no estaba tan lejos de que mi código funcionara :)